# whats the standard way of stating that some sets partition another

Tags: isabelle

I would write `{1, 2} + {3} + {4} = {1, 2, 3, 4}` in maths to say that the sets on LHS partition that of RHS. Is there something similar in isabelle so I don't need to go through all the permutations `{1, 2} intersect {3} = {}` etc.

[EDIT]

I've found this `disjoint` definition in the probability sigma algebra package but is there anything that wouldn't introduce that dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disjoint` is probably the best choice. You can just copy the definition and the few lemmas after it to your own theory.

I will talk to Johannes Hölzl (who made the Probability Theory library) and ask him what he thinks about moving `disjoint` into HOL so that it is available with no extra imports.

Answer (score 1):

In the development version of Isabelle (http://isabelle.in.tum.de/repos/isabelle/rev/53697011b03a) it is now in its own theory file:

```
~~/src/HOL/Library/Disjoint_Sets
```